# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named with virtualenv and need understanding how to structure it for production

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand how python packages/modules work in virtualenv and how I can structure it for distribution .. I have getting this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named lib`. I have a very simple project

```
Project/lib
   - __init__.py
   - calc.py
Project/tests
   - __init__.py
   - test_calc.py
```

I need to be able to access calc.py from the tests and it gives me this error when I import. I understand I should add the Project dir into the sys.path (I have also read the python docs). If I were to distribute this project what do I need to do to make sure the paths are added and the packages are ready to be consumed ? 
do I need a `Makefile` or `setup.py`. There is so many things I am seeing and its a bit confusing. What is the best approach for production?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in saying that you should add the directory to the sys.path variable. Now, all you need to do is, depending on how your code is set up, import the main folder (lib), or import the calc file from lib

Comment: of course I understand I have to import  .. thats not working and I am getting the Module import error because of that

Comment: How are you adding the directory to the path variable?

Comment: ```import os
import sys
print(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
#print(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

Comment: Try this:  import sys

sys.path.append(the_directory_to_your_file)